# Matrix $A$ cannot satisfy $A^3=5I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

If $A \in M(\mathbb{Q},2)$ then it is impossible that $A^3=5I$

I tried to use in Jordan form, but I cannot.

Comment: Try calculating the determinant

Comment: You can use the Jordan form. You should conclude that all Jordan blocks are $1 \times 1$ and that all eigenvalues satisfy $\lambda^3 = 5$.

Answer (score 7):

If it satisfies, $(\det A)^3=25$. And the determinant is not $\mathbb{Q}$-valued. It is a contradiction.